# How to solve a problem with checkpointed invalid __consumer_offsets and producer epoch on partitions of __transaction_state

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two kinds of log entries in server.log

**First kind:**

WARN Resetting first dirty offset of `__consumer_offsets-6` to log start offset 918 since the `checkpointed` offset 903 is invalid. (`kafka.log.LogCleanerManager$`)

**Second kind:**

```
INFO [TransactionCoordinator id=3] Initialized transactionalId Source: AppService Kafka consumer -> Not empty string filter -> CDMEvent mapper -> (NonNull CDMEvent filter -> Map -> Sink: Kafka CDMEvent producer, Nullable CDMEvent filter -> Map -> Sink: Kafka Error producer)-bddeaa8b805c6e008c42fc621339b1b9-2 with producerId 78004 and producer epoch 23122 on partition __transaction_state-45 (kafka.coordinator.transaction.TransactionCoordinator)
```

I have found some suggestion that mentions that removing the checkpoint file might help:

https://medium.com/@anishekagarwal/kafka-log-cleaner-issues-80a05e253b8a

"What we gathered was to:

stop the broker

remove the log cleaner checkpoint file

```
( cleaner-offset-checkpoint )
```

start the broker

that solved the problem for us."

Is it safe to try that with all checkpoint files `(cleaner-offset-checkpoint, log-start-offset-checkpoint, recovery-point-offset-checkpoint, replication-offset-checkpoint)` or is it not recommendable at all with any of them?

Answer (score 1):

I have stopped each broker and moved cleaner-offset-checkpoint to a backup location and started it without that file, brokers neatly started, deleted a lot of excessive segments and they don't log:

> > WARN Resetting first dirty offset of __consumer_offsets to log start offset since the checkpointed offset is invalid

any more, obviously, this issue/defect https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6266 is not solved yet, even in 2.0. 2.  However, that didn't compact the consumer offset according to expectations, namely offsets.retention.minutes default is 10080 (7 days), and I tried to set it explicitely to 5040, but it didn't help, still there are messages more than one month old, since log.cleaner.enable is by default true, they should be compacted, but they are not, the only possible try is to set the cleanup.policy to delete again for the __consumer_offsets topic, but that is the action that triggered the problem, so I am a bit reluctant to do that. The problem that I described here [No Kafka Consumer Group listed by kafka-consumer-groups.sh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54761838/no-kafka-consumer-group-listed-by-kafka-consumer-groups-sh) is also not resolved by that, obviously there is something preventing kafka-consumer-groups.sh to read the __consumer_offsets topic (when issued with --bootstrap-server option, otherwise it reads it from zookeeper) and display results, that's something that Kafka Tool does without problem, and I believe these two problems are connected.
And the reason why I think that topic is not compacted, is because it has messages with exactly the same key (and even timestamp), older than it should, according to broker settings. Kafka Tool also ignores certain records and doesn't interpret them as Consumer Groups in that display. Why kafka-consumer-groups.sh ignores all, that is probably due to some corruption of these records.